WSL2 Windows 11 updated from 22.04 to 24.04. Getting following error
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ubuntu.byteiran.com/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
I tried copying the whole output but I don't have enough reputation on this website yet.

This happens when I try to do sudo apt update

Use a different mirror.
